# Composer create-project is not working even though latest release is available on packagist, but composer install works for same project

Tags: php, composer-php, yii2-advanced-app, packagist

**UPDATED**: *It's working on Ubuntu but not on Windows, is there installation problem with Composer ?*

Package: https://packagist.org/packages/chetan85/yii2-app-advanced-for-shared-hosting

Command: `php composer.phar create-project chetan85/yii2-app-advanced-for-shared-hosting test_shared 2.0.11.2`

Error:
[image]

Same is happening with yii2-advanced app installation:
[image]
[image]

BUT: all the update and install command are working fine. If we downdload .zip file from: https://github.com/chetan85/yii2-app-advanced-for-shared-hosting/releases/tag/2.0.11.2

and do `php ../composer.phar install`
It works perfectly fine.
[image]

Comment: I recommend you'd look here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/392/creating-yii-applications-with-composer/

Comment: Your second error is not the same. That's when you try to install two incompatible libraries, ie maybe they both depend on a different version of each library. 

Try deleting the global composer.lock and updating your libs.

Comment: Second error is, I tried to install the FXP plugin, it's not working either. But if I download the package and then do "composer install", everything works fine. Same happens for Yii2 as well.

Comment: Guys, I have tried this on Ubuntu, its working fine there, Only problem is with windows. I'm not able to install YII2 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@All, The problem here was command i.e
Old command

> php composer.phar create-project
>   chetan85/yii2-app-advanced-for-shared-hosting test_shared 2.0.11.2

New Command

> ./composer.phar create-project
>   chetan85/yii2-app-advanced-for-shared-hosting test_shared 2.0.11.2

We SHOULD NOT be using PHP in command i.e

> <strike>php</strike> composer.phar create-project
>   chetan85/yii2-app-advanced-for-shared-hosting test_shared 2.0.11.2

Then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this
php composer.phar create-project chetan85/yii2-app-advanced-for-shared-hosting test_shared

also check if composer is installed globally
try with 
php composer create-project chetan85/yii2-app-advanced-for-shared-hosting test_shared

Comment: Yes, this is not working as well. have you tried it, did it work for you ??